# Found old bank book of my mothers

Tags: bank-account

I just found my mothers old savings account book from The First National Bank of Chillicothe, Ohio.  Her acct. #xxxxx was i thunk closed in 1-28-54 $1,416.55. But under that she has hand wrote bank in col. which she she went to Columbus, oh next and has deposit $300.00, now leaving total of $1,716.55. So it says so in her book. How can I find out about this since she has now been passed several years but I never noticed this before and someone said to look into it?

Answer (score 4):

First, gather the information you have on her banking history.  She may have accounted for that money and moved it to a new account or otherwise spent it.  I don't expect you'll have much banking documentation from the 1950s, but if you do, then start there and trace the money.

To the extent you can, you may try to contact the banks in question or their successors.  It may be difficult to trace them through mergers or closings.  Again, it's very possible that she spent or transferred those funds and there is nothing to find anyway.

There is also a risk that if the money went unclaimed for too long, then the bank was obligated to escheat any remaining balance to the state of Ohio.  You can try contacting Ohio Department of Commerce about [**unclaimed funds**](http://www.com.ohio.gov/unfd/) and attempt to locate anything that may have rightly belonged to her.  You will need to gather [**documentation**](http://www.com.ohio.gov/documents/unfd_DocumentationRequirementList.pdf) to do so.  You may be able to receive the funds from the state, if it has received them.

Comment: Also, bring documentation of her death (death certificate) plus a will or other document showing that you are the proper heir or executor of the estate. This will allow banks to share private information with you.